# How do I write smart contracts of ethereum in C#

Tags: c#, blockchain, ethereum

I am a C# developer but want to explore blockchain especially ethereum.

Is it possible to write ethereum smart contracts in C#

How would I get started on it? I also explored pluralsight but nothing has been suggested on it. Any pointers are helpful

Comment: As far as I know smart contracts are only written in Solidity. Go to https://www.newline.co/?inf_contact_key=2dc1a421f0e18457f15242d4f9e37fec443f7d01574fac7068bdb0384c09818f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [ethereum.stackexchange.com](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7474/22026) answer, there are only three official languages to write smart contracts in.
Solidity, Serpent and LLL(Lisp Like Language)

<strike>However, here is a an open source project to allow developers to build smart contrats in C#, [EthSharp](https://github.com/EthSharp/ethsharp-compiler)</strike>

And here is a Medium article discussing EthSharp, [Ethereum Smart Contracts in C# - Introducing EthSharp](https://hackernoon.com/ethereum-smart-contracts-in-c-introducing-ethsharp-12c7a5db0b5)

**I went back and noticed that this project is deprecated**

Here is a .NET library to interact with Ethereum blockchain, however I do not believe you can write smart contracts in C# using this library, [Nethereum](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum)

Otherwise, Solidity seems to be the most popular language to write smart contracts in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for Smart contracts in C#, Stratis is doing a great job of that so far. 
I have written a couple and tested on their test net.

They have documentation for their first example, an auction smart contract:
http://stratis-smart-contracts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And the Stratis Development foundation has some walk-throughs to help get you going: 
http://stratisdevelopmentfoundation.com/create_sc/

Their smart contract dev sites ethereum infrastructure often.
It could be what you are looking for.